# Binding specific tracks to hotkeys in foobar2000 possibly via autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, key-bindings, audio-player

I am looking for a way to attach hotkeys to specific tracks in foobar2000. I havent found a way to do it directly through foobar. Ive been trying to write down an autohotkey script which would skip songs until foobars window title matches destined tracks title, but ive been failing so far. If you have an idea on how to do this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First disable this
Library=>Configure=>Shell Integration=>disable "Bring to front when adding new files
Then enable this
Playback=>Playback follows cursor
Then use this

```
^F1::Run,C:\MusicPlayer\foobar2000.exe /add /immediate "C:\path\to\song.mp3" /play
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to attach hotkeys to specific tracks in foobar2000. I havent found a way to do it directly through foobar

Actually, there is a way

We use the ability of [foo_run](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=45223) to bind certain commands to a (global) shortcut.
Additionally we need [foo_cmd_playlist](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=47148) to switch to the correct playlist because the used command [`context_command:play <path_to_mp3>`](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Commandline_Guide) works only if the corresponding playlist is active. Otherwise your track will be appended to the end of the active playlist or send to a new one according to your settings

#### How to set up

1. Download & install two foobar2000 plugins [foo_run](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=45223) and [foo_cmd_playlist](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=47148)
2. Under `Preferences » Tools » Run services` add a new entry for each track you need a shortcut. Enter a proper name as label
   [image]
3. Under `path:` you  enter

   ```
   foobar2000 /playlist-activate:"Radio" /context_command:play http://listen.radionomy.com/themashupradio
   ```

   `/playlist-activate:"Radio"` is where you define the playlist which has your desired track.
   If you have a global playlist with all music in one, just take this playlist and you're fine

   `/context_command:play http://listen.radionomy.com/themashupradio` is the place where you enter the full path to your mp3 (or online stream like my example)
4. At last, we set up a custom shortcut for our new entry under `Preferences » Keyboard Shortcuts`

   [image]

<sup>All hail to the fb2k</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Foobar2000 supports command line parameters. Simply passing the path of the mp3 file to foobar2000.exe works.  Below uses the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
^F1:: Run, %comspec% /c "C:\MusicPlayer\foobar2000.exe "C:\path\to\song.mp3"",, Hide
```